# Efficiently slice and read images using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ray

I have a large satellite image and would like to run an object detection model inference on it. Currently I slice the large image, save the tiles and then read them to have my model output the detections (boxes and masks). I understand this is an inefficient way of doing things, since once the image slice/tile is read, it's no longer required but I'm currently saving it to disk.

Is there a more efficient way to do this process? Perhaps via the multiprocessing or ray libraries?

Comment: Consider multiprocessing+redis(store the detections)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm storing the detections separately in geojson files. Isn't the speed bottleneck due to saving the image slices/tiles to disk?

Comment: If me, I would slice the image to memory and use multiprocessing to improve detecting speed, then use redis to store result. Maybe you should show your code first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) would be a good fit due to the use of shared memory and the ability to run the same code on one or more machines.

Something like the following structure could work.

```
import numpy as np
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def do_object_detection(image, index):
    image_slice = image[index]
    # Do object detection.
    return 1

# Store the object in shared memory.
image = np.ones((1000, 1000))
image_id = ray.put(image)

# Process the slices in parallel. You probably want to use 2D slices instead
# of 1D slices.
result_ids = [do_object_detection.remote(image_id, i) for i in range(1000)]
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

Note that the workers that execute the `do_object_detection` task will not create their own copy of the image. Instead, they will have access to a copy of the image that lives in shared memory.

Another approach if you already have the images in separate files is to do something like the following.

```
import numpy as np
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def do_object_detection(filename):
    # Load the file and process it.
    return 1

filenames = ['file1.png', 'file2.png', 'file3.png']

# Process all of the images.
result_ids = [do_object_detection.remote(filename) for filename in filenames]
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you're suggesting that the image slicing be done within the remote function? Just to recap, my current pipeline is to take the large image, slice and save the slices separately (e.g. 01_01.png, 01_02.png....) and then read the slices to do inference. After which the image slices are deleted since they're no longer needed.

Comment: I see, in that case, if you already have different files, you can define a remote function which takes a single image (or filename) and processes it. I'll update my answer to include this version.